# On blur attached to on focus or separate?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have the following code, will the blur event only be invoked once an element has lost focus, or whenever it is not focused?

```
$('').on("focus", function() {
    // do something
});

$('').on("blur", function() {
    // do something
});
```

What's the difference between that and:

```
$('').focus(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .blur() called." );
});

$('').blur(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .blur() called." );
});
```

And

```
$('').focus(function() {
    // do something
}).blur(function() {
    // do something
});
```

Comment: Only when it looses focus ..

Comment: A `blur` event is just that, it fires when an element loses focus.

Comment: That'd be a lot of browser activity if it was constantly being fired if it wasn't being focused. And FYI https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/blur

Comment: this is two questions. 1) there is no difference, they're three different jQuery ways of doing the same thing. 2) google can in detail explain what blur does, but it only happens when something loses focus.

Answer (score 0):

The `blur` event fires for an element if that element had the `focus`, but loses it.

The `focusin` and `focusout` events `bubble`, the `focus` and `blur` events doesn't

Answer (score 0):

Only when it loses focus ..

Note that this event do not bubble up the DOM (You can not take advantage of event delegation mechanism, use focusout instead to be able to catch this event on a parent element)

Answer (score 0):

The event is triggered whenever the selected element loses focus.

Regarding the rest of the question, there is no difference between the two latest blocks: just the second makes use of jQuery chaining, i.e. the first call returns the selection itself.